# SQlite SELECT WHERE Column = list of unknown number of values

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a list that changes size (and values) depending on the data it gets from a different table. Is there a way to use the list as a variable in place of the `= (?)` in the execute function?

I could add the number of `(?)` needed using a for loop that would add it to the command

```
# some function that adds or changes value of var
var = [1, 2, 3]
cmd = """SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN ("""
for i in range(len(var)):
    cmd += """(?)"""
    print(cmd, i)
    if i < len(var) - 1:
        cmd += """, """
        print(cmd, i)
    if i == len(var) - 1:
        cmd += """)"""
        print(cmd, i)

c.execute(cmd, (var))
```

is there a way for me to just input the list as a whole similar to this.

```
c.execute("""SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (?)""",
          (var))
```

This doesn't work due to an error 'Incorrect number of bindings supplied'. Which makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work for you:

```
# some function that adds or changes value of var
var = [1, 2, 3]
var_to_str = str(var)[1:-1]
cmd = f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN ({var_to_str})"

c.execute(cmd, (var))
```